# SailsJS: Undo API Generation & Clean, Safe Remove for API

Tags: node.js, api, sails.js, sails-generate-auth

#### I'm looking to remove/delete an API I generated using `sails generate api`

I had run `sails generate api user` and went onto implementing the `sails-generate-auth` plugin (tried `sails-auth` too), and the library said it something already exists in my `/models` directory. I deleted *user* from *models*, ran the plugin's command again, and it gave the same message for my `/services` directory -- but there are no files in that directory (except for `.gitkeep`)!

I would like to run a sails command, something like `sails remove api user`, to repeal anything configured for this endpoint -- and essentially start over (this time using sails-generate-auth).

How can I repeal an "`api`"?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no command for deleting an API. You can remove your API by deleting your controller + model of the API.

When you run the command `sails-generate-auth` it automaticly creates a new User API.It returns an error whenever you need to delete anything else so you'll need to delete the files that it requested and the files that it just created...

You also might wanna check out this guide as it might help you alot with the proccess of implement OAuth authentication to your sails app: https://www.bearfruit.org/2014/07/21/tutorial-easy-authentication-for-sails-js-apps/

Comment: Thx for reaching out, Matan, but I had removed both of these (CTRL + Model) and `sails-generate-auth` still hounded me about a non-existent file inside of `api/services`. I was half-assuming that there were some configs that were applied during `sails generate api ...` that generate-auth was noticing -- so I wanted a clean destroy. I'll check out these resources, though -- thx.

Comment: in api/services simply delete the protocol folder if you have no existed file